# Resize the video using MoviePy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, resize, moviepy

Following is my code:

```py
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from moviepy.video.fx.resize import resize
from PIL import Image

video_path = "2textani.mp4"
output_path = "now good1.mp4"
new_width = 640
new_height = 480
 
video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
resized_clip = video_clip.resize((new_width, new_height), PIL.Image.Resampling.LANCZOS) 
resized_clip.write_videofile(output_path)
```

and I am getting following error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
resized_clip = video_clip.resize((new_width, new_height), PIL.Image.Resampling.LANCZOS) 
NameError: name 'PIL' is not defined
```

I have following version

- `moviepy==1.0.3`
- `Pillow==10.0.0`

Comment: Hi, have you tried `Image.Resampling` instead of `PIL.Image.Resampling` in the second to the last line of your code snippet?

Comment: ya i have tried but not worked

Answer (score 0):

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from moviepy.video.fx.resize import resize
from PIL import Image
imort PIL

video_path = "2textani.mp4"
output_path = "now good1.mp4"
new_width = 640
new_height = 480

video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
resized_clip = video_clip.resize((new_width, new_height), 
PIL.Image.Resampling.LANCZOS) 
resized_clip.write_videofile(output_path)
```